# Which Anime/Manga introduced Physical Pilot Damage/ Synchro Rates in a Mecha?

Tags: tropes

Which series introduced Damage Transfers (i.e. Mecha Takes Damage and this Damage is transfered to the pilot) aswell as Synchro Rates between pilot and mecha?

Are there series before EVA?

Comment: I think evangelion is the 1st to introduce that type of series

Comment: Evangelion is a genre deconstruction, so all the aspects from it are taken from previous entries into the genre and just played straight/realistic. If I remember right Eva mostly referenced some show from the 1970s or so, but I forgot the title.

Answer (score 4):

Looking over the TV Tropes [page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Synchronization) it seems that [Magic Knight Rayearth](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/MagicKnightRayearth) (1993-1995) and [Mobile Fighter G Gundam](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/MobileFighterGGundam) (1994-1995) both have the damage transfer aspect and they were produced before Neon Genesis Evangelion (1995-1996).

Magic Knight Rayearth

> The Knights are synchronized with the Rune Gods they've established a contract with. If the Rune God they're riding is injured, it will wound the Knight herself — to the point that breaking the Rune God's weapon will destroy the Knight's own Escudo sword. This synchronization is particularly evident in the Alternate Continuity OAV, where Alcyone's hand was torn apart (and remained a bloody mess afterwards) when Hikaru punched through her Rune God's claws.

Mobile Fighter G Gundam

> In Mobile Fighter G Gundam, Gundam Fighters control their Mobile Fighters via the Mobile Trace System, a skin-tight uniform with various receptors on the outfit to control them through movement. Blows to the Gundam translate to blows towards the pilot and severe damage to the Gundam can really harm a pilot as shown when Sai Saici was forced to rip off one of Dragon Gundam's arms to trick the Mermaid Gundam. It's also said that only the best pilots can handle the suit as those unsuited for it can be injured or killed.